# What happens when somone buys one of these things?

Tags: discussion

[This product](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Raspberry-Pi-Rs-Pi-7-Ports-USB-HUB-Multi-function-I2C-A-D-D-A-RTC-Board-/221179425000?pt=UK_Computing_ComputerComponents_InterfaceCards&hash=item337f5230e8) looks to be a rip off Raspberry Pi.  What happens when people get one of these, then have problems with it and come asking here?  Looks pretty cool really with 7 USB ports, being smaller than a real Pi and having a battery to store the time.  I can see why someone would buy one of these because of these extra features.

I especial love the logo they have made :)[image][image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a quick look this does not appear to be a full Pi clone, but rather an add on board. As evidence look at the cutout where the AV jacks are next to the GPIO pins.

Answer (score 4):

This is an add-on board for the RPi.  Advertised by [Pridopia](http://www.pridopia.co.uk/pi-usb-7-hub-i2c-lite.html).

So anyone coming here asking how to drive it from their RPi should be the same as for any other add-on board.

Incidentally, I have no connection with Pridopia, this isn't any form of endorsement.